# How to restore removed packages

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, restore

I install the Open Broadcast Software (OBS) , I had a software center issue

so I tried to remove it from terminal  with this command

```
sudo apt autoremove obs
```

after that it's remove a system packages not the program 
i think system use it for render the display or something similar 
that's a screenshot of chromium v52 after command process finish 
another one for open file dialog 
[image: open file dialog]
[image: chromium v52] 
and this is a history.log of apt , display removed packages 
[link(github raw)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pro-devel/Cortana/master/history.log)
i running a Ubuntu 16.4 LTS

any help please :_:

Comment: Please always mention at least your Ubuntu release. Please edit and add it.

Comment: @CelticWarrior edited

Answer (score 0):

Open Broadcast Software installation instructions (Ubuntu 14.04+)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install obs-studio
```

Recommended: Install `ppa-purge` -> `sudo apt install ppa-purge` and run it to uninstall and revert all changes made by OBS:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
```

Additionally, `autoremove` has no parameters and the list of removed package contains only the ones that were no longer needed and also unrelated to any graphical glitch.

Comment: my problem not with the obs studio now 
the problem is i removed a system packages and that's make system nasty